# get the sum of the maxs group by

Tags: linq, sum

I have this table

```
EquipmentId  Value  Date
1            2      11/04/2013
1            1      11/04/2013
2            3      11/04/2013
2            2      10/04/2013
2            5      10/04/2013
3            1      10/04/2013
3            3      11/04/2013
```

I want to group these items by date, and have a dictionary with the date as a key and the sum of the maxs of the all equipments values in that day

the result would be like this

```
[10/04/2013: 6]   // 6 = 5 (as the max of values of the the equipmetId 2) + 1 (as the max of values of the the equipmetId 3)
[11/04/2013: 5]   // 5 = 2(as the max of values of the the equipmetId 1) + 3(as the max of values of the the equipmetId 3)
```

I managed to make the query to get this without the sum, meaning for only one equipment.

```
var consumptionValues = (from c in context.ConsumptionSet
                         join pi in context.PropertiesInstanceSet on c.PropertiesInstanceID equals pi.PropertiesInstanceID
                         join ep in context.EquipmentPropertiesSet on pi.EquipmentPropertiesID equals ep.EquipmentPropertiesID
                         join e in context.EquipmentSet on ep.EquipmentID equals e.EquipmentID
                         where (e.EquipmentID == equipmentId && pi.ProprietesName == ProprietesName.Energy && c.Date <= DateTime.Now && c.Date >= firstDayDate)
                         group c by SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", c.Date) into grp
                         select new
                         {
                             dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)grp.Key.Value - 1,
                             value = grp.Max(c => c.Value),
                         }).ToDictionary(c => c.dayOfWeek.ToString(), c => c.value);
```

It's the complete query with all the joins, in the example I just gave a simplified example.

Is it possible to do this in one single query ?

Comment: Is it LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say I'm not sure it will work, but you should give it a shot:

```
var consumptionValues = (from c in context.ConsumptionSet
                         join pi in context.PropertiesInstanceSet on c.PropertiesInstanceID equals pi.PropertiesInstanceID
                         join ep in context.EquipmentPropertiesSet on pi.EquipmentPropertiesID equals ep.EquipmentPropertiesID
                         join e in context.EquipmentSet on ep.EquipmentID equals e.EquipmentID
                         where (e.EquipmentID == equipmentId && pi.ProprietesName == ProprietesName.Energy && c.Date <= DateTime.Now && c.Date >= firstDayDate)
                         group new { c, e } by SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", c.Date) into grp
                         select new
                         {
                             dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)grp.Key.Value - 1,
                             value = grp.GroupBy(i => i.e.EquipmentID).Sum(g => g.Max(i => i.c.Value)),
                         }).ToDictionary(c => c.dayOfWeek.ToString(), c => c.value);
```

Comment: OMG you just made my day. I didn't really get your code but it works! Thanks a lot